# Java regular expression to normalize MAC address

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that represents a MAC address, but does not show the higher-order byte for each address term if it is zero.  That is, instead of an address of the form `00:11:22:33:44:55`, I would have an address of the form `0:11:22:33:44:55`; instead of an address of the form `00:1b:17:00:0b:31`, it has the form `0:1b:17:0:b:31`.

I would like to convert a string missing a MAC address's high-order byte (if that high-order byte is zero) to a string that explicitly includes its high-order byte.  Obviously, I could split the incoming string on `:` and then walk through each element.  But I thought it might be cleaner/faster to do it with a regular expression (specifically string's [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method).  However, the regular expression that I wrote doesn't work.  As an example,

```
String original = "0:1b:17:0:b:31";
String replaced = original.replaceAll("(^|:)([0-9a-f])(:|$)","$10$2$3");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

prints `00:1b:17:00:b:31`.  Essentially, it misses inserting the higher-order byte for the last `b`.  I think this is because the regular expression that I'm using has overlapping matches: the colon used to delimit the end of one match must also be used to delimit the beginning of a subsequent match if there are two or more entries missing high-order bytes.

Is there a way to allow for overlapping matches using Java's regular expressions?  Alternately, is there a regular expression that I'm not thinking of that could be used here?  Or do I really have to take a multi-line approach (e.g., string-splitting and iterating, using the above regular expression multiple times until the result is the same is the input, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String replaced = original.replaceAll("\\b\\w:", "0$0");
```

`\b` is a "word boundary", so `\b\w` will match a word character (letter or number) at the start of input as well as after a colon. `$0` is (a back reference to) the entire match. No scary look arounds :)

---

Some test code:

```
String original = "0:1b:17:0:b:31";
String replaced = original.replaceAll("\\b\\w:", "0$0");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Output:

```
00:1b:17:00:0b:31
```

Comment: You would need to replace `\b([\da-f])(?=:)` with `0$0`

Comment: @naomik thanks for pointing that out, but the solution is actually simpler than that. See edit

Comment: @vks, my point was that `\d` isn't going to match all hexadecimal chars

Comment: @anubhava `\d` matches all hexadecimal characters?

Comment: @naomik no `\d` matches any digit. I've changed it to `\w` - any letter or digit (or underscore), which in the context of mac addresses is good enough

Comment: What about if the last group doesn't contain the higher order byte? Like `0:1b:17:0:b:1`. Guess, this would solve it: `\\b\\w(:|\\b)`

Comment: I had actually edited it. `original = original.replaceAll("\\b([\\da-fA-F])\\b", "0$0");`

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|(?<=:))(?=.(?::|$))
```

You can use `lookarounds` to find the position and insert a `0`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/20

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String replaced = original.replaceAll("\\b(?=[\\da-fA-F]\\b)", "0");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX8nJ5/1)